# MPI_Bcast synchronization between receiver and sender

Tags: matrix, process, parallel-processing, mpi, communication

Imagine having n processes each hold a matrix of 2 rows and 8 elements (stored linearly, not in 2D). I want each processes to communicate its rows to all processes with lower ranks. For instance, the process with rank 2 communicates its rows to the processes with rank 1 and 0; the process with rank 0 does not communicate its rows to any process.

I'm having issues deciding how to approach this problem. Using MPI_Bcast is a possible solution, but I can't seem to get the operation to work as expected. Below you can see a sample of the code I'm executing.

```
// npes is the number of processes obtained from MPI_INIT
// The value for i below is used to specify the number of 
// rows that will be received
for (i = (npes - rank - 1) * rowsPerProcess; i > 0; i--) {
  // Receive
  MPI_Bcast(temp, columns, MPI_DOUBLE, i/rowsPerProcess, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  printf("I'm %d and I received from %d\n", rank, i/rowsPerProcess);
}

if (rank != 0) { // rank 0 does not send data
  for (row = rowsPerProcess - 1; row >= 0; row--) {
    for (j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
      //matrix_chunk is the per process matrix of 2 rows
      temp[j] = matrix_chunk[row*columns + j];
    }
    // Send
    printf("I'm sender %d\n", rank);
    MPI_Bcast(temp, columns, MPI_DOUBLE, rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  }
}
```

The output I receive is the following:

```
I'm 1 and I received from 1
I'm sender 2
I'm sender 2
I'm 0 and I received from 2
I'm 0 and I received from 1
I'm 0 and I received from 1
I'm 0 and I received from 0
I'm 1 and I received from 0
I'm sender 1
I'm sender 1
```

It seems that the first receive MPI_Bcast call is executing as a sender operation. I have also printed the contents of the received temp matrix and they are not what I expect them to be.

More than trying to correct this mess, I would like to get a perspective on how I can perform this particular communication problem. I feel like I'm approaching this from the wrong direction. Please let me know if you have any suggestions!

Comment: `mpi_bcast` is a collective operation, all the processes in the communicator specified (in your code `MPI_COMM_WORLD`) all make the call and it's designed for, well for broadcasting from a root process to all other processes, so I'm not sure it is the right routine to use for your intended pattern of communications.  I think I'd have started with matched `mpi_send` and `mpi_recv` in the pattern you want.

Comment: Though it is theoretically possible to create n-1 subcommunicators with the `i`-th subcommunicator encompassing ranks `0` to `i-1` from `MPI_COMM_WORLD`, which will allow you to use `MPI_BCAST`, there might be more effective solutions. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The problem I'm trying to solve is reducing a matrix to its row reduced echelon form. Before the code I posted above, I have the matrix in row reduced form (elements below diagonal are 0's). The step you see above is essentially the inverse operation, reducing the elements above the diagonal to 0.

Comment: Why do you want to pass the matrices to the other processes? If they are to do an operation on it, your problem sounds like it could make use of MPI_Scan. With a user defined operation, this might be suitable for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented matched mpi_send and mpi_recv as suggested by High Performance Mark. The problem immediately made sense when I thought of it through this approach.